# How can i restrict our html text from coping by other users in flex?

Tags: apache-flex, air, flex3

In my air application, i have displayed text content in either in html container or textarea container. whenever anyone select this content, he/she can easily copy the content.

I want to restrict my text from copy. Any content of the my application, should not be copy by any user..

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the [selectable](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/TextArea.html#selectable) property of textarea.

Comment: Thanks loxxy 
it's working for textarea, but not for html container

Comment: Which html container are you talking about? There is no class called htmlcontainer in flex...

Answer (score 2):

[Bindable]
   private var htmlT:String;

```
 htmlT = "<b>name</b>"                                                            
 <mx:Text htmlText="{htmlT}" selectable="false" />
```

i tried but no other properties for  ban selecting in html container. 
I dont know this is right manner. you can try this code.

```
<s:Group width="100%" height="100%">
    <s:HGroup width="100%" height="100%" >
    <mx:HTML  location="http://www.google.com" width="100%" height="100%"/>
</s:HGroup>
<mx:HBox width="100%" height="100%" backgroundColor="white" backgroundAlpha="0.01"/>
</s:Group>
```

Comment: +1 agree on your solution. My question is why all of you throw Bindable on each variable. Do you think it is always needed ?

Comment: no , im not think. but now i just give this for value getting soon

Comment: I am using many html container like 
var html1:HTML = new  HTML();
I want to restrict selectable property of this html container.
If we can put any html code for restrict this please share.

Comment: i hav just add some code to the answer. One unvisible child is also added as cover in html container. pls try this.